# Nest js - error No overload matches this call

Tags: javascript, nestjs

js and currently learning on making a crud operations.

i got an error on users.service saying

> No overload matches this call.   Overload 1 of 3, '(this: (new () =>
> User) & typeof BaseEntity, entityLikeArray: DeepPartial[]):
> User[]', gave the following error.

and

> Property 'save' does not exist on type 'User[]'.

**on await user.save();**

this is my users.service

```
import { CreateUserDto } from './dto/create-user.dto';
import { User } from './user.entity';

@Injectable()

    export class UsersService {
    
        async create(createUserDto: CreateUserDto) {
            const user = User.create(createUserDto);
            await user.save();
        
            delete user.password;
            return user;
        }
        
    }
```

create-user.dto.ts

```
import { IsEmail, IsNotEmpty } from "class-validator";
    export class CreateUserDto{
        @IsEmail()
        email: string;
    
        @IsNotEmpty()
        password:string;
    }
```

users.controller:

```
export class UsersController {
  constructor(private readonly usersService: UsersService) {}

  @Post()
  create(@Body() createUserDto: CreateUserDto) {
    return this.usersService.create(createUserDto);
  }
}
```

users.entity:

```
import { BaseEntity, BeforeInsert, Column, CreateDateColumn, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, UpdateDateColumn } from "typeorm";
import * as bcrypt from 'bcryptjs';

export class User extends BaseEntity {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column()
    email: string;

    @Column()
    password: string;

    @Column()
    @CreateDateColumn()
    createdAt: Date;

    @Column()
    @UpdateDateColumn()
    updatedAt: Date;

    @BeforeInsert()
    async hashPassword() {
        this.password = await bcrypt.hash(this.password, 8);
    }

    async validatePassword(password: string): Promise<boolean> {
        return bcrypt.compare(password, this.password);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you provide your entity?

Comment: @HaiAlison i added the entityt, please check it

Comment: it seems you missed @Entity() in the entity file, try adding it

Comment: @HaiAlison it's still having the same error after i add it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the answer myself,

i did this in my async create on UsersService:

```
constructor(
    @InjectRepository(User) private userRepository: Repository<User>
  ){}   //and i add this constructor to use Repository

async create(createUserDto: CreateUserDto) {
    const user = this.userRepository.create({
      ...createUserDto // this is the change
    });
    
    await user.save();

    delete user.password;
    return user;
  }
```

and then it resolve the error!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Seem you have imported wrong entity. I saw you have name `users.entity.ts`

But, when you import in service

```
import { User } from './user.entity';
```

Probably, it should be like

```
import { User } from './users.entity';
```

Comment: i've changed it, but it still throwing the same error